# How to show single widget in else condition in ListView.Builder

Tags: flutter, list, listview, android-listview, flutter-listview

I am fetching data from Firestore in TabBar. If my particular condition is false the ListView.Builder shows the single image which is in else condition, but this has not happened, the image shows multiple time

[image: Here is One TabBar Screen]

[image: Here is second TabBar Screen]

If my required data not available it should show image only sinlge time but its showing multiple times

I mention two TabBar codes, please give me solution.

```
      StreamBuilder( stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('recentPublished').snapshots(),

 builder: (context, snapshot) { if(!snapshot.hasData) {
 return Center(
child: Text("Not Available", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500), textAlign: TextAlign.center,)); } 
else{ return ListView.builder( 
itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length, 
itemBuilder: (context, index) 
{ UserModel targetUser = UserModel( uid: snapshot.data.docs[index]["userId"] .toString(), fullname: snapshot.data.docs[index]["rideOfferBy"] .toString(), profilepic: snapshot .data.docs[index]["riderProfileUrl"] .toString(), );

return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("rideRequests").doc(snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["userId"\]).collection(snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["rideId"\]).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if(!snapshot.hasData)
          {
            return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
          }
          else{

            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (kDebugMode) {
                  print("INDEX =======\> " + index.toString());
                }
                
                  if ((snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\['senderId'\] == userId)) {
                    return Column(
                    children: \[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text("Driver Name: "+snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["receiverName"\].toString()),
                            subtitle: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: \[
                                Text("From: "+snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["pickUpPlace"\].toString()),
                                Text("To: "+snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["destination"\].toString()),
                                Text("Date: "+snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["date"\].toString())
                              \],
                            ),

                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("This ride status is " + snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["status"\].toString())
                    \],
                  );
                  } else {
                    return Image.asset("assets/images/noData.jpg");
                  }

                        
 StreamBuilder( 
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('recentPublished').snapshots(), 
builder: (context, snapshot) { 
if(!snapshot.hasData) { 
return Text("No Data"); } 
else{ return ListView.builder( itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
 itemBuilder: (context, index) { 
UserModel targetUser = UserModel( uid: snapshot.data.docs[index]["userId"] .toString(), fullname: snapshot.data.docs[index]["rideOfferBy"] .toString(), profilepic: snapshot .data.docs[index]["riderProfileUrl"] .toString(), ); return StreamBuilder( stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("rideRequests").doc(userId).collection(snapshot.data.docs[index]["rideId"]).snapshots(), builder: (context, snapshot) { if(!snapshot.hasData) {
 return CupertinoActivityIndicator(); } else{ print(snapshot.data.docs.length.toString());
                          
                           return
                          (snapshot.data.docs.length \> 0) ?
                          ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          primary: false,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            print("Cancel Request INDEX ==========\> "+ index.toString());
                            return (snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\['status'\] == 'cancelled') ? Column(
                              children: \[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Card(
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      title: Text(snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["senderName"\].toString()),
                                      subtitle: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: \[
                                          Text("From: "+snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["pickUpPlace"\].toString()),
                                          Text("To: "+snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["destination"\].toString()),
                                          Text("Date: "+snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["date"\].toString())
                                        \],
                                      ),

                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text("This ride is cancelled by " + snapshot.data.docs\[index\]\["receiverName"\].toString())
                              \],
                            ) : Image.asset("assets/images/noData.jpg");
                          },

                        ) : Image.asset("assets/images/noData.jpg");
                      }
                    },);
                },);
            }
          },
        ),
                
                
              },

            );
          }
        },);
    },);
}
```

},
),